# How to calculate rolling covariance matrix from a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark 2.2.0 DataFrame of currency prices where I add the returns to.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
val prices = spark.read.json("prices.json")

// make a window function and convert prices to returns
val window = Window.partitionBy("currency").orderBy("time")
val lagPrice = lag(col("close"), 1).over(window)
val percentReturn = col("close") / col("lastClose") - 1d
val logReturn = log(col("close") / col("lastClose"))

val returns = prices.withColumn("lastClose", lagPrice)
                    .withColumn("return", percentReturn)
                    .withColumn("logReturn", logReturn)
```

Now I want to calculate a rolling Covarance Matrix (like a moving average) of all currencies using a window function. But I can not find any documentation or examples.